# How to send boolean parameter from extjs request to server?

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs4

I want to send an extjs request to the server.One of the parameter in the extjs request is of the type boolean.

```
params: 
{
name : 'John',
active : true/false
}
```

On the server side the action has a bean as a parameter (MyBean) which hold the values sent by the extjs request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "save", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void saveUser(MyBean bean) {
System.out.println("name : " +bean.getName());
System.out.println("active : "+bean.getActive());
```

}

Value Object is as follows :

```
public class MyBean 
{
public String name;
public boolean active;
//getters & setters
}
```

The code bean.getActive() prints false even if the value sent by the extjs code is true.
Please tell me what is required to send a boolean value as parameter from the extjs code.

Comment: You could change the parameters of `saveUser` from `MyBean bean` to `String name, boolean active`.

Comment: What is it, a servlet? Rest service?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObjectToSend = {

  "name": "jhon doe",
  "active": true
}

Ext.JSON.encode(myObjectToSend);
```

Then you can receive it in java as a single object, decode it (with jackson for example) and then access the object atributes ... best regards